# USB port monitoring

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, usb

I need to monitor the USB ports of Windows and Linux computers to know if a pen drive has been connected.

How do I do that?

I need it via Linux script or Windows.

Comment: SO is not a script or code writing service. Please add a sample of your own work so far.

Comment: What do you mean 'As linux or Windows script'?  What OS are you running this on?

Answer (score 2):

You can use WMI Events on Windows (**On Windows ONLY**, as WMI, Windows Management Instrumentation is only available on Windows) to do an action when device state changes.

Assuming you're on Windows though, and using PowerShell, here's how you trigger an event during a [DeviceChangeEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-devicechangeevent), like when a USB drive is added.

```
Register-WMIEvent -query "Select * From Win32_DeviceChangeEvent where EventType = '2'" `
-action {
   #Do Something when a device is added
   Write-host "Device added at $(Get-date)"
}
```

When I plug in a USB hub, which has a lot of ports and devices connected, this is what I see:

```
Device added at 06/10/2021 09:27:59
Device added at 06/10/2021 09:27:59
Device added at 06/10/2021 09:28:00
Device added at 06/10/2021 09:28:00
Device added at 06/10/2021 09:28:00
```

Comment: Oh man, usually it's bad to answer a question when nothing was provided on their end, but this is some good info lol. I had no clue this existed. Thank ya(:

Comment: I already had an answer to this on my blog, so it was easy to copy/paste and help. I personally don't like when a question is closed rather than let the asker have a chance to fix their question.  It makes SO an unfriendly place.  Not on my watch at least!

Comment: While I agree, it encourages other to post similar questions while not allowing other legitimate questions to be seen. Anyways, good stuff, and if you got a blog full of Powershell related stuff, I'd love to see it!